# Slick2D shader crashes, but only after a while

Tags: opengl, java, shaders, slick

I'm using Slick2D's ShaderProgram for shader-based drawing in my game. Some players report that after 3-10 minutes, the game inevitably crashes hard during what appears to be a setUniform4f operation that's happened thousands of times before:

```
[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBShaderObjects.nglUniform4fARB(IFFFFJ)V
J  com.zarkonnen.airships.Appearance.draw(Lcom/zarkonnen/catengine/Draw;DDDDILcom/zarkonnen/catengine/util/Clr;Z)V
```

[Full Log](https://gist.github.com/Zarkonnen/eb5984cc0f448c086196)

Why might this happen? Is it a transient problem, or maybe a driver issue? I'm confused that this happens not when the shader is bound, or when textures are set, but at the point of this utterly mundane operation of setting a 4f value. I'm in fact pretty lost here, as I can't even repro this on any of my own machines.

This is the culprit function in its entirety:

```
public void draw(Draw d, double x, double y, double w, double h, int ms, Clr tint, boolean flipped) {
    if (shaderLoadFailed) {
        drawFallback(d, x, y, w, h, ms, tint, flipped);
        return;
    }

    if (tex == null) {
        tex = loadTex(SPRITESHEET);
        if (tex == null) {
            shaderLoadFailed = true;
        }
    }
    if (sp == null) {
        try {
            sp = ShaderProgram.loadProgram(
                    AGame.getGameDirectoryPath("data/passthrough.vert"),
                    AGame.getGameDirectoryPath("data/frag.frag"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            shaderLoadFailed = true;
        }
    }

    if (shaderLoadFailed) { return; }

    sp.bind();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.getTextureID());
    sp.setUniform1i("tex", 0);
    if (tint == null) {
        sp.setUniform4f("tint", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    } else {
        sp.setUniform4f("tint", tint.r / 255.0f, tint.g / 255.0f, tint.b / 255.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    Img img = frames.get((ms / interval) % frames.size());

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    if (flipped ^ isFlipped) {
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX, img.srcY);
        glVertex2d(x + w, y);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX, img.srcY + img.srcHeight);
        glVertex2d(x + w, y + h);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX + img.srcWidth, img.srcY + img.srcHeight);
        glVertex2d(x, y + h);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX + img.srcWidth, img.srcY);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    } else {
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX, img.srcY);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX, img.srcY + img.srcHeight);
        glVertex2d(x, y + h);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX + img.srcWidth, img.srcY + img.srcHeight);
        glVertex2d(x + w, y + h);
        glTexCoord2d(img.srcX + img.srcWidth, img.srcY);
        glVertex2d(x + w, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    sp.unbind();
    TextureImpl.bindNone();
}
```

And the shaders FWIW:

passthrough.vert

```
void main() {
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

frag.frag

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 tint;

void main(void) {    
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, floor(gl_TexCoord[0].st) / 1024.0) * tint;
}
```

As you can see, there's very little to them.

Comment: 0xc0000005 is a memory access violation, there is little info of why this might happen, the crash might be caused by one of your functions. if you used logging it could be much more trivial to debug. Send of your clients a version with logging enabled.

Comment: @concept3d The problem is that it's happening somewhere within native/library code: https://gist.github.com/Zarkonnen/eb5984cc0f448c086196

Comment: This **could be** a driver-issue since the dll mentioned in the threaddump (ig4icd32.dll+0x543589) belongs to NVIDIA and it shouldn't be a bug in lwjgl since you can't reproduce it. Unfortunately i can't help you further with this problem, you should contact NVIDIA's technical support and show them your log, they should know which function-call this is and maybe they already knew this bug and can tell you more.